# Правка sql запроса и кода

Tags: c#, sql

Мне нужно посчитать количество родившихся и умерших за определенный период.

Начал с новорожденных,потом по аналогии с умершими.

Есть два DatePicker первый start,второй end.

```
 int prib = 0;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";

        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        string my_querry3 = "SELECT COUNT (*)  FROM [Новорожденные] where[Дата рождения] between'"+start.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")+"'And '"+end.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")+"'";
        OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry3, conn);

        prib= (int)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
        pribavg.Text = prib.ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Ошибка может быть не в запросе, а в выводе.

Мне нужно конкретное количество родившихся за выбранный период.
Потом буду вычислять прибыль или убыль населения.

*Уважаемый магистр кода tym32167 ,мне нужна правка в коде. Одной ссылкой мне трудно помочь*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Параметризируйте запрос.

Comment: @Igor И какой же параметр написать?И у кого? У where ?

Comment: Одинарные обрамляющие кавычки у литерала - это строки. Литералы даты у MS Access имеют несколько иной формат.

Comment: @Akina  так что ли ("#dd/MM/yyyy#") тоже ошибка

Comment: А квотить слэши кто будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с литералами дат у MS Access.

```
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            string my_querry3 = "SELECT COUNT (*)  FROM [Новорожденные] where[Дата рождения] between #" + start.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "# And #" + end.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "#";
            OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry3, conn);

            prib = (int)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
            pribperiod.Text = prib.ToString();
```

Comment: Как вам уже советовали, используйте [параметры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) и не нужно будет думать о форматах строк.